# Windows Phone 7 Silverlight DataTemplate HyperlinkButton content

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I'm trying to make a list that is populated by external data and I have a datatemplate for it.
Each element of the list is composed of an image and two textblocks, and is linked to a specific page.

I'm trying to do this but when I wrap the structure with an HyperlinkButton, I just get a blank page.

I don't know if I'm doing something stupid wrong or it's not possible to have so many items in an HyperlinkButton. If it's not possible to do it this way, can someone guide me to the best solution to do this? Here's the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,140,0,0" Background="White">
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="itemList" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <HyperlinkButton>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="480">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/app;component/Images/degradat_cela.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Left" />
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="430*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="38" Width="38" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFFF003F" Padding="1">
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listImage" Width="36" Height="36" Source="{Binding image}" />
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5 12 0 0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="title" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="description" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding subtitle}" FontSize="14" />
                    </Grid>
                </HyperlinkButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I will also accept any suggestions to make my code better, as I'm new to .NET and I probably don't do things the best way!

Comment: Why do you need HyperlinkButton? I think in most cases you are enough just with Grid.

Comment: How do I link to another page without an HyperlinkButton or a click event?

Comment: You can use NavigationService within Page as an reaction to ListBox.SelectionChanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the HyperlinkButton and instead use the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox. So add this property to your ListBox:

```
SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged"
```

Then in your code behind do this:

```
private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(string.Format("/Drilldown.xaml?Index={0}",(sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex),System.UriKind.Relative));
}
```

This code assumes a drilldown page that uses a query string to change it's layout.  This is just for example. If instead of index you wanted to reference some property of the bound item you could instead do something like this (assuming an ID property):

```
int itemID = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as MyApp.Model.myItem).ID;
NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(string.Format("/Drilldown.xaml?ID={0}",itemID),System.UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: The thing is that it isn't a dropdown... I just want like a stack, one item below the other. I got the example from: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Binding-the-Note-Class-to-the-ListBox-DataTemplate.
Thank you

Comment: @enkara A ListBox will show items one after another (it is NOT a dropdown at all), the selectionchanged event fires when a user taps one of the items in the listbox, the eventhandler shown above then navigates to a page based on the tapped item (I assume this is what you are trying to accomplish by using a HyperlinkButton).

Comment: @enkara in the referenced sample they have a HyperlinkButton along with other controls (*the HyperlinkButton does not contain them*). If you merely want a link, then use the HyperlinkButton as shown in the example. But if you want the *entire item* to act as a "link" (which will be more consistent with the WP7 user experience) then you will need to follow the method I have outlined above.  Please give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I want the entire item act as a link, I will try what you have suggested, sorry for my misconceptions!

Comment: just perfect, thank you very much for the detailed examples and the patience!